# Why unable to find the exact path for grains storage in master?

Tags: salt, devsecops

I am trying to completely remove the grains from the system. I have one master and one minion setup(minion id= minion1). I am doing

> salt minion1 grains.ls

that is listing me all the grains

Now I removed data.p which is the cache memory for the grains in master

```
path : /var/cache/salt/master/minions/minion1/data.p
```

Without running a salt_sync or any other command for sync I am again doing.

```
 `salt minion1 grains.ls`,
```

It's returning the same result.(The grains are still somewhere stored.

Where exactly it is storing the grains and how to delete that?

Answer (score 2):

These are built-in grains, which are collected at minion startup. [Here's the code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/tree/develop/salt/grains) responsible for generating them.

You cannot remove them, but you can [overwrite them](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/index.html), for example to an empty value in `/etc/salt/grains`:

```
osfinger: null
```

or with [grains execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html): `salt minion1 grains.delval osfinger`.

Keep in mind that some of the core grains are essential for the correct functioning of salt, e.g. module providers for `pkg` module rely on them.

Comment: so there is no location as such of grains storage in minion and master.

Comment: Yes, there's only cache which you can clear with `salt-run cache.clear_grains` or sync grains with `salt-run saltutil.sync_grains`.

Comment: I tried something:                                                                                    
1.Created some grains in minion
2 Synced the grains with the master
3 Cleared cache from the master
4 Then also it is showing the grains
PS: This condition is after clearing cache and not syncing

Comment: Yes, the cache is just that, a cache. When the grains are needed, and they are not in cache, they will get synchronized automatically. It's impossible to remove core grains.

Comment: I tried the same with custom grains but they are still present.

Comment: For custom grains use the `salt minion1 grains.delval customgrain` as the answer suggest, then. See: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/index.html